# MVC3 and Table and how to generate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a List<> of items which I want to display in a 3 column table. So, 3 items per row. How best would I do this in an MVC3 application? I am converting from a Asp .Net app, where I created a Table in code, and then just displayed the table.

Should I return the List<> to the View, and in the view, somehow create the table cells and rows? The objects I am returning have things like description, image URL, views etc. The table will display photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just released a jQuery plugin which MVC3 support (you can use view models) which generates the table for you.

https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Table

### Install package

```
install-package griffin.table.mvc3
```

### Create a view model (`Models\User.cs`)

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

### Create a view (`Views\Home\Index.cshtml`)

```
@model GriffinTableViewModel<DemoProject.Models.User>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.GriffinTableForm("myTable", new{action = "Items"})) {}

@Html.GriffinTable("myTable", Model)

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myTable').griffinTable({ fetchAtStart: true, pageManager: $.griffinTableExtensions.pageManagers.showMoreLinkPager });
    });
</script>
```

### Create two actions in your controller (`HomeController`)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Items(GriffinTableAjaxRequest model)
{
    var users = new List<User>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        users.Add(new User {Id = i + 1, FirstName = "first" + i, LastName = "last" + i});

    }

    // [.. do sorting here using model.SortColumn and model.SortOrder ..]

    var pagedResult = users.Skip((model.PageNumber - 1)*model.PageSize).Take(model.PageSize);
    return this.GriffinTable(pagedResult, users.Count);
}
```

There are four different implementation sample usages [here](https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Table/tree/master/Source/mvc3/Examples/Basic)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx) is a nice solution from Phil Haacked's blog using a tabular template, although it's MVC2 so if you're using razor not so good.

You could also opt for a "quick and dirty" solution, just iterating the List<> in the view and spitting out the HTML from there. Scott Gu gives an overview of doing this with Razor [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

Comment: I would add that my answer is a simple solution with limited functionality & sexiness. Whereas, @jgauffin's response is both quite cool and sexy :)

Answer (score 1):

MVC3 has a `WebGrid` class that renders tables:

```
@{
    if (!this.Model.Items.Any())
    {
        <div>No records found.</div>
    }
    else
    {
        var grid = new WebGrid(this.Model, 
            canPage: false);

        @grid.GetHtml();
    }
}
```